# open interval written as countable union of closed intervals

Tags: general-topology

Show that any open interval can be written as a countable union of closed intervals.

Show that any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set.

Show that any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set.

Answer (score 9):

$$[a,b]=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(a-1/n,b+1/n)$$

and As Nicholas said, $$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=\frac{2}{b-a}+1}^{\infty}[a+1/n,b-1/n]$$

We started from $n=\frac{2}{b-a}+1$ because for $[a+1/n,b-1/n]$ to be an interval, $b-1/n>a+1/n$

Comment: Just as a side note, should the union not start from $n = \lceil\frac{2}{b-a}\rceil +1$, as we need the integers? :). Since we are not quaranteed $\frac{2}{b-a}$ is an integer.

Answer (score 6):

The interval $(a,b)$ is the union over all integers $n\gt \frac{2}{b-a}$ of the closed intervals $[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$. The geometry becomes quite clear if one draws a picture, and then formal verification is not far behind.

The infinite open intervals can be handled in a similar way.

The other parts of the problem can be obtained as consequences of the above result.

For the $F_\sigma$ question, perhaps you can use the fact that any (non-empty) open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of open intervals. Then for the $G_\delta$ part take complements.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but I feel that you should have first determined what the OP was having trouble with before having answered.

Comment: True. I assumed that since three questions were asked, all of them gave trouble. It may be that the hints for the other two questions will not be sufficient.

Comment: Formal verification relies on the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* $(a,b)=\bigcup_{a<c<d<b}[c,d]$